# Get a numeric value from specific string using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid and I am getting selected row's html by its id using JavaScript.

```
var parentRow1 = document.getElementById('__' + parentrowid).innerHTML;
```

this will return me the following html:

```
<td class="rgExpandCol">
<img title="Expand" onclick="$find(&quot;&quot;)._toggleExpand(this, event); return false;" 
src=" style="border-width:0px;"></td><td>TEST</td><td>my details</td><td>1</td><td>01/06/2011</td>
<td>198307</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<span id="lblDCount">2</span>
</td>
<td>
<span id="lblUCount">1</span>
</td>
<td>
<input name="$btn" id="btn">
</td>
```

Is there a way to get this portion(the number count will not be static), and get the number value then substract it by one:

```
<span id="lblUCount">1</span>
```

so final result will be `<span id="lblUCount">0</span>` it it is 2 then 1 and so on

Comment: You could use parseInt() or if its more complicated than you stated use regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var count=$('#__' + parentrowid).find('#lblUCount').text();

var finalCount=parseInt(count) -1 ;
```

**updated**

to assign it back..

```
$('#__' + parentrowid).find('#lblUCount').text(finalCount);
```

Comment: I get parentRow1.find is not a function

Comment: it does return the value now but how do I assign the value back to label

Comment: It makes no sense to use `find` with an `id` unless you specifically want it not to be found outside the parent. @Sam1: Again, if you're using `id` attributes, they **must** be unique on the page.

Answer (score 5):

Since the span itself has an `id`, you don't need to first get anything from the row:

```
var lblUCount = $("#lblUCount");
lblUCount.text(parseInt(lblUCount.text(), 10) - 1);
```

I suspect, though, that you have multiple rows and thus multiple copies of that `span`. If I'm right, then your HTML is invalid, because `id` values **must** be unique on the page. So I'd change it so you give those spans classes instead:

```
<span class="lblUCount">1</span>
```

...which means you *do* need to start with the row, then use `find` to find it:

```
var lblUCount = $('#__' + parentrowid).find('.lblUCount');
lblUCount.text(parseInt(lblUCount.text(), 10) - 1);
```

There I'm using [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) with an ID selector to get the row, then [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) with a class selector to find the `lblUCount` span within the row. Then [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) to get the text of the cell, [`parseInt`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) to turn that into a number, and then `text` again to *set* the new text of the cell.

Comment: I have tried find solution and it does give me the lable value..but when subtracting it says : lblUCount.text is not a function

Comment: @Sam1: If jQuery is properly loaded and `$` isn't being used by some other library, the above works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is AFAIK the simplest solution.  It relies on the "function" parameter version of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) which both passes the original text to the supplied function, and then re-inserts the return value back into the element.

```
$('#lblUCount').text(function(idx, text) {
    return parseInt(text, 10) - 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery like this:

```
var $el = $('#lblUCount'), 
          val = parseInt($el.text());
val--;
$el.text(val);
```